# UIDataDetectorTypeLink not working - iPhone

Tags: iphone, url, uitextview, hyperlink

I am using the following sample code to add a link to a UITextView in a UITableViewCell, but it is not creating a link. I have done this before without issues... Has something changed with the recent iOS upgrade?

```
UITextView *myView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
myView.text = @"this is http://google.com link";
myView.editable = NO;
myView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
//cell is the TableView's cell    
[cell.contentView addSubview:myView];
[myView release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried simply putting this code in a subview on a normal view and works great for me (iOS 4.2), maybe the bug is somewhere else (or maybe frame is empty)

//EDIT: and tried for content view in TableViewCell, works also great

Just to have the question (maybe) solved: you have to reset `myView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;` every time you reload the table.

Comment: Ahh... you are right. I created a new project it and it works. This is not going to be fun to figure out.

Comment: Apparently when I call reloadData on the TableView, it 'turns off' all the url links. I can see it happening, all the links are visible, then when reloadData is called on the table, all the links disappear.

Comment: for me the links also disappear but after a second the appear again

Comment: ahh ok, I know your problem, you have to re-set the myView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink; every time the cell is reloaded, then it will work ;)